# JS focus to change query, blur on display

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, innerhtml

I hope I can explain this 'problem' I have.

- I want to click on text (in my case editable div)
- Edit a "code/command/query/instruction
- On release/blur replace the inner content with generated data

It is working... but I believe I could do it with less code.. Can I?
Let me show you what I have so far. I don't mind if I need to change the editable div.

```js
/* I don't like messy code */

var header = document.getElementById('header');
var lead = document.getElementById('lead');
var article = document.getElementById('article');

header.addEventListener("blur", render);
header.addEventListener("focus", edit);

lead.addEventListener("blur", render);
lead.addEventListener("focus", edit);

article.addEventListener("blur", render);
article.addEventListener("focus", edit);



function render() {
      this.setAttribute("XPQ", this.innerHTML );
      this.innerHTML = 'dynamic data from db (example)  bla, bla bla bla and more bla';
}

function edit() {
      this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("XPQ");   
}
```

```css
/*
    ---  CSS Isn't important  ---
*/

body{font-family:arial}h4{colour:red;}strong{colour:blue;}h4#header,#lead,#article{background:rgba(205,205,5,0.1);padding:3px;}
```

```html
<h4 id="header" contenteditable="true" xpq="$post[1]['header']  --  (example)">dynamic data from db (example)</h4>
<p><strong id="lead" contenteditable="true" xpq="$example">this is the same as above (example)</strong></p>
<p id="article" contenteditable="true" xpq="/html/body/div[1]"> but of course all 3 have difrent data. I just tried to keep is simple to explain my problem. My idea is to use Javascript with PHP. Only I'm not so great with Javascript jet. I wonder if there was a clear way to make the JS.  Without using on every element  a blur and focus listener.</p>
```

I'm curious how I can improve my code.
I'd would be thankful for your help.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I Like to learn more JS. and I want to know if this is the right way to do it.
It is working but I guess there is a better way... do I really need to set for every element and focus and blur? So there is not a big problem. Only searching for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good to add event listeners to all the elements by getting them alone use `getElementById`. You can have a same class on all the elements which want to have this behavior. And then use `querySelectorAll` to get them and `forEach` to `addEventListner` on them

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.editable').forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener("blur", render);
  x.addEventListener("focus", edit);

})




function render() {
      this.setAttribute("XPQ", this.innerHTML );
      this.innerHTML = 'dynamic data from db (example)  bla, bla bla bla and more bla';
}

function edit() {
      this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("XPQ");   
}
```

```css
/*
    ---  CSS Isn't important  ---
*/

body{font-family:arial}h4{colour:red;}strong{colour:blue;}h4#header,#lead,#article{background:rgba(205,205,5,0.1);padding:3px;}
```

```html
<h4 id="header" class="editable" contenteditable="true" xpq="$post[1]['header']  --  (example)">dynamic data from db (example)</h4>
<p><strong id="lead" class="editable" contenteditable="true" xpq="$example">this is the same as above (example)</strong></p>
<p id="article" class="editable" contenteditable="true" xpq="/html/body/div[1]"> but of course all 3 have difrent data. I just tried to keep is simple to explain my problem. My idea is to use Javascript with PHP. Only I'm not so great with Javascript jet. I wonder if there was a clear way to make the JS.  Without using on every element  a blur and focus listener.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks allot!  I knew It could be better.  It's a lot cleaner like this. I needed it because I want to have a couple of 10 more ;)